# QUERY and order by the first date of column

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I perform a query on a sheet and then I want to sort the result according to the first date of each range that I gather each category.

I will to link you to the file and then as soon as someone tells me how to write, I'll update this post for the people who read it.

[My Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zP2i-Tx3QKEZjU4SbiyJg4xWwtTZt9seDDzSrRxlOjg&authuser=0)

I use:

```
=QUERY(Foglio1!A:C; "select B,SUM(C) group by B order by SUM(C)")
```

I need the first date of everyone to be sorted with QUERY!

Comment: This question is unclear - the promise to update it was not kept. The linked spreadsheet has been trashed, and the final version available to general users is significantly different than described in this question (or shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25666538/1677912). Therefore, the question is of no value to the community.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=QUERY(Foglio1!A:C; "select B,SUM(C),MIN(A) group by B order by MIN(A)")
```

Comment: Perfect. It works. I love people speechless and efficient like you.

Comment: Please @Juliusz, can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696283/sum-values-of-the-column-circular-dependency

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about Excel or Google spreadsheet?

Here is how-to based on your link to your Google Docs Spreadsheet:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No, friend. I need "QUERY"; I use =QUERY(Foglio1!A:C; "select B,SUM(C) group by B order by SUM(C)") and I need the first date of everyone to be sorted with QUERY!

Comment: What/who is, what do you mean with "everyone"? ("...and I need the first date of everyone to be sorted with QUERY!")

Comment: Sorry. I mean every row.