# Sum values of the column. Circular dependency

Tags: google-sheets

I don't know how to say in language, but I need what I realize in [this spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zP2i-Tx3QKEZjU4SbiyJg4xWwtTZt9seDDzSrRxlOjg&authuser=0)

In attached spreadsheet there are two sheets: "How it is now" and "How it should be".

I use this formula in other sheets, but now it doesn't work correctly:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1; SUM(INDIRECT("D2:"&"D")); IF(LEN(A:A); (E:E+F:F+G:G)-B:B)))
```

Please remove the trailing FALSE text in the first column after the cell range.

**In D1 I need a SUM of D2:D. But there is an error "Circular dependency".** Try please.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone interested, the answer from myself:

`=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1;sum(if(isnumber(B:B);E:E+F:F+G:G-B:B;));if(len(A:A);if(isnumber(B:B);E:E+F:F+G:G-B:B;);)))`